# how to combine a functions in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, function, frontend

I have two functions, one is to delete section and the other is to delete sub section. Both functions are very similar so I'm thinking about combining them into a single function with if statements but I'm not sure why it's not working. Any suggestion or help will be appreciated.

This is how it look

```
  deleteSection(sec) {

    this.HelpService.deleteHelpSection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
      const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.id);
      this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id)
      if (~index) {
        this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
          this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id);
        })}})}

  deleteSubsection(sec) {
    this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
      const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.parentId);
      if (~index) {
        this.mappedSections[index].subSections = this.mappedSections[index].subSections.filter((subsection) => subsection.id != sec.id)
```

I'm trying to do like this

````
  isSection: boolean = false;
  isSubsection: boolean = false;

  delete(sec) {

    if(this.isSection){
      this.HelpService.deleteHelpSection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
        const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.id);
        this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id)
        if (~index) {
          this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
            this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id);
          })
        }})   

    }if(this.isSubsection){
        this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
          const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.parentId);
          if (~index) {
            this.mappedSections[index].subSections = this.mappedSections[index].subSections.filter((subsection) => subsection.id != sec.id)
          } }) }}
```

HTML
```
Delete section button
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="delete(section)" *ngIf="isSection">
</button>

Delete subsection button
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="delete(section)" *ngIf="isSubsection">
</button>

```
````

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks ok, so maybe you can try to take a second parameter in your delete method it can be a boolean like `delete(sec, isSection: boolean)` and then in your html:

```
Delete section button
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="delete(section, true)" *ngIf="isSection">
</button>

Delete subsection button
<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="delete(section, false)" *ngIf="isSubsection">
</button>
```

Comment: Although this seems logical it is actually considered a non clean code. What would it mean if you say isSection = false? What would that be then? The logic performed seems similar but is actually completely different. It should live in two separate functions. That would also facilitate future changes if the design of sub sections would alter for example.

Answer (score 0):

if you want either one of the delete button to be shown at a time then,i belevive since you have initalized false to both isSection and isSubsection there should be some code making either one of them true then the logic works fine.
if there is no code making either one of them true then you wont see any of the delete buttons in the UI,

if you want both the buttons to be present always in the ui and make different actions then simply do as follows

```
delete(sec:any,issection:Boolean) {

if(isSection){
  this.HelpService.deleteHelpSection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
    const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.id);
    this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id)
    if (~index) {
      this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
        this.mappedSections = this.mappedSections.filter(section => section.id != sec.id);
      })
    }})   

}else{
    this.HelpService.deleteHelpSubsection(sec.id).subscribe(() => {
      const index = this.mappedSections.findIndex((value) => value.id == sec.parentId);
      if (~index) {
        this.mappedSections[index].subSections = this.mappedSections[index].subSections.filter((subsection) => subsection.id != sec.id)
      } }) }}
```

<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="delete(section,true)">

<button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="delete(section,false)">